# WHERE clause using IF or CASE statement to check between two dates OR default to past 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out a query that if start date and end date are NULL, then search between the current date and the last 30 days. If the start date and end date are NOT NULL, then search between the start date and end date. I am having a hard time figuring out the query structure. This is for SQL Server 2016. So far I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getInboundTrackingGraphs
    @chartType nvarchar(50) = null,
    @geoID int = null,
    @startDate date = null,
    @endDate date = null,
    @currentDate date,
    @previous30Days date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @currentDate = GETDATE()
    SET @previous30Days = DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())

    SELECT *
    FROM InboundTicket
    WHERE DateOpened BETWEEN
        CASE WHEN @startDate IS NULL AND @endDate IS NULL THEN @currentDate AND @previous30Days
        ELSE  @startDate AND @endDate
        END
END
```

Error message:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: What if `@startDate` is null but `@endDate` is not null?

Comment: Possible to replace the case statement with 2 Iif statements? ... Between Iif(@startdate is null and @enddate is null, getdate(), @startdate) and iif(the same but adjusted for @enddate)

Comment: Getdate() also includes time. Does startdate and enddate have similar appearence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need the `CASE`.  Simple boolean logic will do:

```
WHERE (@startDate IS NULL AND @endDate IS NULL AND
       DateOpened >= @previous30Days AND DateOpened <= @currentDate
      ) OR
      (DateOpened >= @startDate AND DateOpened <= @endDate)
```

Second, don't use `BETWEEN`.  You are already confused by it.  In your case the confusion is putting the more recent date first.  So, keep your life simple and use explicit comparisons.

Note that this version will return nothing if only one of the dates is `NULL`.  That is the logic in your question.  I suspect it is not the best approach.

And, the final condition doesn't need to test for `NULL`, because the comparisons will never return true if any of the operands are `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

The use of [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) can make this very simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM InboundTicket
WHERE DateOpened >= COALESCE(@startDate, @previous30Days)
  AND DateOpened <= COALESCE(@endDate, @currentDate)
```

Noel